# Trying to change colour of one variable in ggplot geom_bar dependent on the string

Tags: r, ggplot2, phyloseq

I have a for loop to run through a tonne of microbiome data (using `phyloseq`) and generate plots for multiple experiments.

```
  ggplot(data_M1, aes(x = Sample, y = Abundance, fill = get(i))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
    facet_wrap(vars(Status, Time.Point, Treatment), scales = "free", ncol=2)+
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, keywidth = 1, keyheight = 1, title = i))+
    ylab(yaxisname)+
    ggtitle(plotname)+
  ggsave(ggsavename, last_plot())
```

Example outcome: [image: example of figure produced]

What I am trying to do though is make all the "_unclassified" samples/ sequencing data grey... so maybe I need some kind of if statement with str_contains?

Happy to dput a reproducible example if required but someone might have a simple solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Like you want to lump all the other categories together? `forcats::fct_collapse` or `forcats::fct_other` should help. A reprex would definitely be useful to do more than speculate. Also, you're missing a few `+`s in your ggplot calls

Comment: right! on it. also thank you - I've been mucking about with it hence the missing +s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@camille's comment about a *minimal* reproducible example is germaine.  We need know nothing about your `facet`s, `guide`s or call to `ggsave` to answer your question.

First, generate some test data

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(
       Species=rep(c("s__reuteri", "s__guilliermondii", 
                     "o__Clostridiales_unclassified", "k__bacteria_unclassified"), 
                   each=4),
       Sample=as.factor(rep(1:4, times=4)),
       Abundance=runif(16)
     )
```

Generate custom labels and colours

```
labels <- unique(d$Species)
# Make sure length of availableColours is long enough to accommodate the maximum length of labels
availableColours <- c("red", "blue", "green", "orange", "yellow")
legendColours <- ifelse(str_detect(labels, fixed("unclassified")), "grey", availableColours)
```

Create the plot

```
d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sample, y=Abundance, fill=Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(labels=labels, values=legendColours)
```

Giving

[image]

If you want to "pool" all the unclassified species, then

```
d1 <- d %>% 
        mutate(
          LegendSpecies=ifelse(
                          str_detect(
                            Species, 
                            fixed("unclassified")
                          ), 
                          "Unclassified", 
                          Species
                        )
        )

legendColours <- ifelse(str_detect(unique(d1$LegendSpecies), fixed("Unclassified")), "grey", availableColours)

d1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sample, y=Abundance, fill=LegendSpecies)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(labels=unique(d1$LegendSpecies), values=legendColours)
```

Giving

[image]

Comment: ah amazing thank you! I hadn't gotten around to adding the relevant data but this has worked perfectly. thank you!